Determine the area of biggest rectangle containing exactly one "X"
Your input is a rectangular 2D char array, such as:
.X.......X
..........
.....X....
..X.......
........X.
.X........
..X.....X.
X.........
....X.....

Your goal is to find the area of biggest rectangle within this input data which contains only one "X". In this case it's 40.
Other testcases:
1
X

0, (or None, null, or equivalent for your language)
.

5
X.X
X.X
.X.
X.X
X.X

152
...X...................................
.................XX............X.......
.........X.............................
.......................................
..................................X....
.................X.....................
.X.......................X.............
............XX...................X.....
...........X..X.........X..............
.....................................X.
......X................................
.................X...........X.........
.............................X.........
.......................................
.XXXXXXX............................X..
.....................X.................
.......................................
.....X.................................
...........................X...........
..X....................................

And here's a working implementation in Python. This is not a contender and is meant to provide better understanding of the problem:
# Author: Ben Stokman <ben.stokman@protonmail.com>
# Title: Selfish Space Code Golf Example Implementation
# Description: Example Solution for "Selfish Space" Code Golf Exercise
# Usage: Pass input data as a file name for second argument

# Returns the area, then the row and column of the item inside it.
# @return if size is zero, bounding box contains at least two items inside it, or the box isn't valid
# @return -1,-1 for row and column if none is found.
def getBoundingBoxSize(data:list[list[int]], row1:int, col1:int, row2:int, col2:int) -> (int, int, int):
    # Don't consider point pairs that don't go from top left to bottom right
    if row1 >= row2 or col1 >= col2: return 0,0,0
    
    # Location of found singular 
    foundRow = -1
    foundCol = -1
    
    # For all indecies inside the smaller box
    for row in range(row1, row2, 1):
        for col in range(col1, col2, 1):
            # Check to see if there's even an item here
            if data[row][col] != "X": continue
            # Check to see if there has already been an item found in this box
            if foundRow >= 0 or foundCol >= 0: return 0,0,0
            
            # Mark off that the single cell is 
            foundRow = row
            foundCol = col
    
    # Return area
    return ((row2-row1)*(col2-col1)), foundRow, foundCol

def calculateAnswer(data:list[list[int]]) -> int:
    # Get the number of rows and columns
    maxRow = len(data)
    maxCol = len(data[0])

    # Stores the maximum bounding box size for each location in the input data
    # max[(row,col)] = maximum size bounding box with only one item in it, being (row, col)
    max = {}

    # Iterate through all possible start and end rows and columns
    import itertools
    for row1, row2, col1, col2 in list(itertools.product(range(maxRow), range(maxRow+1), range(maxCol), range(maxCol+1))):
        # Don't consider point pairs that don't go from top left to bottom right
        if row1 >= row2 or col1 >= col2: continue
        
        # Check to see if there's only one item within this bounding box
        size, foundRow, foundCol = getBoundingBoxSize(data, row1, col1, row2, col2)
        if size == 0 or foundRow < 0 or foundCol < 0: continue
        
        # Check to see if this bounding box gives a bigger maximum size for the specific location
        if (foundRow, foundCol) in max and max[(foundRow, foundCol)] >= size: continue
        
        # Update if needed
        max[(foundRow, foundCol)] = size

    # return maximum size as per the problem
    trueMax = 0
    for item in max:
        size = max[item]
        if size > trueMax: trueMax = size
    return trueMax

# Read input file
import sys
data = [list(line.strip()) for line in open(sys.argv[1], "r")]

print(calculateAnswer(data))


Should the rectangle contain at most one x or exactly one x?

@mousetail'he-him' The 0 case implies that return falsy in case no X exist, but this should be explicitly mentioned

Related (but this one is tagged restricted-complexity).

Can we choose the two possible characters of the input? Or input a 2D numeric array of zeros and ones?

@LuisMendo It seems that people do that anyway. Not sure about the rules on this forum. But I say no to both.

About the rules: flexible input is preferred; see here and here

Brachylog, 24 bytes
{ṇ₂ẹs\scLọ∋["X",1]∧Ll}ᶠ⌉

Try it online!
Expects input as a string with ., X, and \n.
Explanation
{                    }ᶠ⌉    Find max solution of:
 ṇ₂                           Input split by lines,
   ẹ                          each line to list of chars.
    s\s                       Get a transposed submatrix,
       cL                     concatenate it; set it to L.
         ọ                    Get counts of each letter in L.
          ∋["X",1]            Assert it has ["X", 1].
                  ∧Ll         Output length of L.

The s\s\ trick for getting submatrices is stolen from another question. We don't need the actual submatrix though, so we just concatenate.

R, 125 119 bytes
\(x)max(apply(expand.grid(rep(list(1:nrow(x),1:ncol(x)),2)),1,\(s,r=x[s[1]:s[3],s[2]:s[4]])(sum(r=="X")==1)*length(r)))

Attempt This Online!

MATL, 30 25 bytes
&fh!"1G88=@1$l&2Y+m@p*vX>

Try at MATL online! Or verify all test cases.
Explanation
The code first turns characters . and X into 0 and 1 respectively.
It then computes 2D convolution (the key to success) with rectangular masks of all sizes (m,n) up to the input size, filled with the value 1. If the convolution output contains 1, meaning that some of the shifted versions of the mask covered exactly one X, then m·n is a potential result.
The code outputs the maximum (computed cumulatively) of 0 and all those potential results.
        % Implicit input: M×N character array containing 'X' and '.'
&f      % Two-output find: gives row and column indices of each character in
        % the input, as column vectors      
h       % Concatenate horizontally. Produces an (M*N)×2 matrix
!       % Transpose. Columns are all [m; n] with m = 1,...,M and n = 1,...,N
"       % For each column, say [m; n]
  1     %   Push 1 (*)
  G     %   Push input again
  88=   %   Compare each entry with 88. Gives 1 for 'X', 0 otherwise
  @     %   Push [m; n]
  1$l   %   Matrix of ones with size m×n
  &2Y+  %   2D convolution, keeping only valid part, without edge effects (**)
  m     %   Ismember? Gives true if 1 (*) is present in (**), false otherwise
  @     %   Push [m; n]
  p     %   Product: gives m*n
  *     %   Multiply. Gives m*n if 1 was present in (**), 0 otherwise
  v     %   Concatenate vertically with accumulated result so far, if any
  X>    %   Maximum
        % Implicit end
        % Implicit display


Uiua, 41 chars
G←/◇⊂⍚⧈□⊙¤⍜¯⇡⊸⧻
/↥⍚(/↥≡(×⊃⧻(=₁/+)◇♭)G⍉)G

Pad Link
Thanks to Ruben Verg for helping define G

In G, ⊙¤⍜¯⇡⊸⧻ can be +₁⇡⧻⟜¤ for -1. And it was Maddie who wrote the definition of G you're using currently, not me (: Also, as far as I can tell, you're supposed to take the input using the actual characters . and X, so you should add =@X to F.

38 bytes with a char array input, or 37 with sided subscripts.

Charcoal, 42 bytes
ＷＳ⊞υιＩ⌈Ｅυ⌈Ｅ⊕κ⌈Ｅι⌈ＥＥ⊕ξ⭆✂υλ⊕κ¹✂ςπ⊕ξ¹∧⁼¹№πXＬπ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list of newline-terminated strings. Explanation: Lots of brute force but still manages to complete the large test case on TIO.
ＷＳ⊞υι

Read in the rectangle.
Ｉ⌈Ｅυ⌈Ｅ⊕κ⌈Ｅι⌈ＥＥ⊕ξ⭆✂υλ⊕κ¹✂ςπ⊕ξ¹∧⁼¹№πXＬπ

Generate all of the subrectangles, then for each one concatenate their rows into a single string, then take the length of those strings containing exactly one X and print the longest length.

This is 108 bytes (UTF-8 encoding)

It's not UTF-8. Add the -x flag if you want to see the hex dump.

JavaScript (Node.js), 121 bytes
f=S=>!!S.replace(/./g,c=>X+=c>[++L],L=X=0)<X?Math.max(...[/.*\n?/,/\n?.*$/,/^./mg,/.$/mg].map(r=>f(S.replace(r,'')))):X*L

Try it online!
-2 bytes by l4m2.
Expect a string with ., X, and \n.

Python, 90 bytes
f=lambda A:max(map(f,[A[1:],A[:-1],A[:,1:],A[:,:-1]]))if(T:=(A=="X").sum())>1else A.size*T

Attempt This Online!
Expect a np.array with "." and "X".

JavaScript (Node.js), 121 bytes
f=(x,l,u=y=0,r,d,z=~(r-l)*~(d-u),s=1)=>y=x.map((R,i)=>R.map((c,j)=>1/r?s-=!(1+c|j<l|j>r|i<u|i>d):f(x,j,i,l,u)))|s|y>z?y:z

Try it online!
Python 3, 146 bytes
lambda x:max(W*H*(1==sum(x[D-j][R-i]>'W'for j in r(H)for i in r(W)))for R in r(len(x[0]))for W in r(2+R)for D in r(len(x))for H in r(2+D))
r=range

Try it online!

Maple, 171 bytes
proc(M)map(n->combinat:-choose([$n,$n],2),[op(1,M)]);max(0,map(z->`if`(numboccur((y:=[seq(M[z[]])]),"X")=1,nops(y),NULL),[seq(seq(map(`..`@op,[i,j]),i=%[1]),j=%[2])]))end;

proc(M)                      # accepts an n x m Matrix of "X" and "."
map(n->combinat:-choose([$n,$n],2), # all different pairs from
                             # [1..n,1..n] so it includes [i,i]                                     
      [op(1,M)]);            # map for each dimension
# Now have: [ [[1,1],[,2],..,[n,n]], [[1,1],[1,2],..,[m,m]] ]
max(0,                       # default value if no "X"
   map(z->                   # for each z = [i..j,k..l]
                             # use as indexing to extract submatrix
                             # if one "X" then return num. elements
      `if`(numboccur((y:=[seq(M[z[]])]),"X")=1,nops(y),NULL),
                             # map works on ranges made from above
       [seq(seq(map(`..`@op,[i,j]),i=%[1]),j=%[2])]
      )
   )
end;

